# Amazon Elasticsearch index replication between two AWS ES Cluster/Domain?

Tags: aws-elasticsearch

I have a use case wherein I need to replicate one of ES Domain index(main) to another ES Domain index.
I am aware of the Cross Cluster Replication feature in elastic search but I don't think it is applicable for AWS Elasticsearch. I need the solution for AWS ElasticSearch.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy indexes from one es domain to another via connecting both to the same S3 bucket. Then you can store one's snapshot and restore to another.
You can follow this doc:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/migration.html

Answer (score 0):

You can follow following steps to migrate elasticsearch data from one cluster to another :

1. Register snapshot repository to source cluster.
2. Register the same snapshot repository to destination cluster.
3. Take snapshot (lets call it snap1) of source cluster in repository.
4. Restore snapshot in destination cluster.

If the source and destination cluster belongs to different aws accounts, then you need to setup access permissions which is nicely described in blog : https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/migrate-amazon-es-domain/